# Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable - Web API issue

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable

So I am trying to create a simple web API 2 with VB in VS2015. However the code I did get working **only returns a simple string**, where the **Web Api expects serialized data** so XML or JSON could be returned.

```
'Here I initialize and populate my object       
Public widgetObj As New widgetModelClass("bottle", 1)


' Below kind of works, but simply returns a string **instead** of 
' the serialized data for XML or JSON the Web API should return. 
' it returns: {"Name":"bottle","ID":1}
 Public Function GetValues() As widgetModelClass
     Return widgetObj 
 End Function
```

The below code *fails* with the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

```
Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of widgetModelClass)
    Return widgetObj
End Function
```

I have defined my **model class** as follows

```
Public Class widgetModelClass
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal id As Integer)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.ID = id
    End Sub

    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set
            m_ID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The **full error message**:

> An error has
>   occurred.Unable to cast object of type
>   'TestApp.widgetModelClass' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestApp.widgetModelClass]'.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: The error is because you are returning a single `widgetModelClass`, which is not an `IEnumerable(Of widgetModelClass)`.  You could return a list with the single item: `Return New List(Of widgetModelClass)() From { widgetObj }`... however, I am confused by this: "Below kind of works, but simply returns a string instead of the serialized data for XML or JSON the Web API should return. it returns: {"Name":"bottle","ID":1}", which to me sounds like it is doing exactly what you are wanting, i.e. it's returning JSON data.

Comment: I disagree: proper JSON is:  [{"Name":"bottle","ID":1}]. However, returning the list does work.

Comment: That is JSON for an array of objects.  Without [] is perfectly valid JSON for a single object.

Comment: Perhaps without [] is ok, but the bottom line is when I sent the the webservice request with content type of application/xml and application/json both returned only: {"Name":"bottle","ID":1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample you return `widgetObj` but it is not of an instanse of the `IEnumerable(Of widgetModelClass)` as you want.

You have to change declaration to return one instanse of the `widgetModelClass`:

```
Public Function GetValues() As widgetModelClass
    Return widgetObj
End Function
```

or your return statement to return `IEnumerable(Of widgetModelClass)`:

```
Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of widgetModelClass)
    Return New List(Of widgetModelClass)(New widgetModelClass() { widgetObj } )
End Function
```

Comment: Returning the list worked and I could request both JSON and XML types. Only JSON would return with your 1st declaration.